# Restrict game to play locally

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, locking

How to restrict the game locally?. I know the browser sitelock. But i do not know how much it is effective.

I played the games in http://www.gameark.com/. If you download the games from this website, you cannot play it locally. How to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: The games probably require certain information to be presented to them at start up.

Comment: Look up the url address from where it is loaded. If the game is not running from yourWebsiteUrl then just stop();

Comment: Is it effective? by getting the website url and restricting?

Comment: @user1610823 - sure, you want to prevent this access from ordinary users and it will, hackers will surely work out how to avoid your sophisticated security locks:) so not worth to spent too much time on this especially when it is just this type of lock.

Comment: The title is ambiguous. Do you want to **prevent** users from playing the game locally, or **only** allow users to play it locally?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using http://www.swfshield.com to do this without pain.

What they do is actually converting your swf into binary or some sort, and wrap it inside a loader (I'm not sure.. It's just my guess...). I use this swfshield to protect my swfs from being decompiled and being stolen.

It will not load locally if you do single domain lock. So, basically, it won't literally load in any domain other than the specified domain.

Additionally: I've tried at least five different decompilers to decompile the protected swf from swfshield.com, but none of them were able to get a single hint about the swf. :)